# How to bind JSON data to noUiSlider?

Tags: php, json, ajax

this is my first time using noUiSlider and I am stuck on how to bind the data from my json file to pass to the slider and filter my result.
I am returning values from wp db in form of json data as follow:

```
0:
price:"100"
carat:"0.70"
clarity:"VVS2"
color:"D"
condition:"good"
1:
price:"20"
carat:"0.30"
clarity:"VF1"
color:"F"
condition:"Excellent"
```

As you see some of key values are strings.
I am planning to make one slider for each key.
How do I set the min and max and all other values in between to equals or loop through my key values from the json values?
I am using the following format from php:

```
$json_array = array();
var myData = json_encode($json_array);
```

These are just sample data, I just stuck at the binding section. How do I loop through all my colors for example {D, F, G, D, E, A} or condition {excellent, good, very good, bad}. In nouiSlider its all integers and I am sure somehow these key values correspond to that array?

Thanks in advance for your help.